# Javascript turns my php var 0000001000 to 512

Tags: javascript, string, int

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='show($ID);'>ID</a>
```

my $ID is 0000001000.

what my show() function gets is 512 instead of 0000001000

I have tried cast $ID to string using String() and .toString() but still i do a alert() it returns me 512.

i read something about octal mode. how can i prevent or correct this ?

i want my function to read 0000001000

Comment: Show us the code for `show`.

Comment: You have to echo the php var, otherwise it's treated as the string '$ID'. `show(<?php echo $ID; ?>);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass it as a string:

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='show(\"" . $ID . "\");'>ID</a>";
```

Otherwise it is automatically cast from octal to decimal notation as `oct(1000) === dec(512)`.

Comment: That will pass the string literal `"$ID"` to `show`, probably not what you meant :P

Comment: @jbabey Yes, now it should be more descriptive :)

Comment: @jbabey Why is that? Since when can't you echo a PHP variable in a string?

Comment: @jbabey Doesn't matter, they shouldn't need to concatenate a string. Can't you just do: `echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='show(\"$ID\");'>ID</a>";` ? Or am I wrong? I guess I don't know what the original code was, but I thought it might be something like that. Shouldn't the only thing the OP needs be the escaped quotes before and after the `$ID`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears `0000001000` is being interpreted as octal (credit to @Oscar Lopaz) (512) when you pass it to your show function. Try passing it as a string instead:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('" + $ID + "');">ID</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

A number starting with zero is taken as an octal (not binary!) in Javascript. 1000 in octal == 512 in decimal. You should handle the value as a string to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Nice catch on the octal. I didn't bother to think about it hard enough